# Windows Phone: Slider movement locked by Textblock Binding

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I am trying to do a simple example of the typical slider.value binded to a textblock.  I have tried to maintain it so simple that I cannot find what would be the problem here.

I have this simple XAML code and NO code behind:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    .......
    .......
    .......

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Slider x:Name="mySlider" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

With this code, the slider movement is locked.  If I remove the TextBlock binding then all works fine (but no value on TextBlock, of course) :-)

It seems so simple that I know something very, very stupid is locking my brain.

I have tried the 'Binding' in anyway you can imagine, but no luck at the moment.

Any help and any explanation, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting maximum and minimum properties on your slider.

OK, try a stackpanel for your layout:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Slider x:Name="mySlider" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" Height="30" />
</StackPanel>
```

I think the issue is that your controls are sitting on top of each other.